# Android migration from Opengles 1.0 to Opengles 2.0, textures?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I currently have an OpenGLES 1.0 engine with a very large code base, and I'm in the process of migrating to OpenGLES 2.0

Thanks to [this](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/opengl/opengl-es20.html) I've been able to get past the lack-of-matrices obstacle, but before I continue changing thousands of lines of code I would like to know a few things that I haven't been able to find with Google.

**First**, has the process of applying textures changed at all? I know that the old fixed-pipeline did a lot of the dirty work for you, but I don't know if textures were part of that. Will I have to create shaders for that as well? (think glTexEnvf, glTexParameter, glBindTexture, etc)

**Second**, has there been any changes with blend modes, or will that also need custom shaders?

**Third**, has there been any important change to glDrawElements? (In other words, will my existing calls work without modification)

**Fourth**, can anyone recommend some good books or tutorials for learning how to make shaders and how they work? I learned quite a bit from the large amount of iPhone tutorials on the internet and from the tutorial I linked above, but the latter doesn't contain any in-depth explanations and the former doesn't contain any Android code, and I'm new to shaders >_<

Answer (score 0):

1. Things like binding textures and the `glTexParameter`s (like filtering or wrapping modes) work like before. But you now have to do the texture application inside the fragment shader yourself. Therefore you now basically implement `glTexEnv` yourself.
2. Blending works like before. These operations are done after the fragment shader in the same way like in ES 1.
3. Not to `glDrawElements` itself. But now you have to use custom vertex attributes and corresponding vertex shaders for processing them, istead of the builtin attributes (like vertex, normal, color, ...) from ES 1.